# Incrementing function argument after jQuery .clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php script that prints out price values for current page in a table. Each row is a different price for 1 product and can be edited.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="content" id="page_prices">
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th>description</th>
        <th>sku</th>
        <th>single</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>currency</th>
        <th width="25"></th>
</thead>
<tbody> 

<?php
for($i=0; $i<$count_prices; $i++)
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input name=\"price_description[]\" type=\"text\" id=\"price_description\" size=\"20\" value=\"".$prices[$i]['description']."\">";
  echo "<td><input name=\"price_code[]\" type=\"text\" id=\"price_code\" size=\"5\" value=\"".$prices[$i]['code']."\">";
  echo "<td><input name=\"price_pcs[]\" type=\"text\" id=\"price_pcs\" size=\"5\" value=\"".$prices[$i]['pcs']."\">";
  echo "<td><input name=\"price_qty[]\" type=\"text\" id=\"price_qty\" size=\"5\" value=\"".$prices[$i]['qty']."\">";
  echo "<td><input name=\"price_value[]\" type=\"text\" id=\"price_value\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"10\" value=\"".$prices[$i]['price_value']."\" onChange = \"CalcSale(this.form, $i);\">";
  
  echo "<td><input name=\"otstupka_pr[]\" type=\"text\" id=\"otstupka_pr\" size=\"5\" value=\"0\" onChange = \"CalcPerc(this.form, $i);\">";
  echo "<td><input name=\"regular_price[]\" type=\"text\" id=\"regular_price\" size=\"5\" value=\"".$prices[$i]['real_price']."\" onChange = \"CalcSale(this.form, $i);\">";
  echo "<td><input name=\"valid_to[]\" type=\"date\" id=\"valid_to\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"10\" value=\"".$prices[$i]['valid_to']."\">";
  echo "<td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

?>
  </tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr><td colspan="7"> <a href="javascript: void(0)" id="add_page_price" class="add">Add price</a>
  </tfoot>
  </table>
```

There are 2 functions that calculate based on user input: `CalcSale` and `CalcPerc`. Each of them uses the value of the input and the counter `$i` in order to calculate separately on every row. When a user decides to add a new price and clicks on `add_page_price` the last row is cloned with:

```
$j("#add_page_price").click(function(){
 $j("#page_prices tbody tr:last").clone().appendTo("#page_prices tbody");
})
```

The question is: How can I clone the last row and increment the argument `$i` in the `onChange = \"CalcSale(this.form, $i);\"`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't use the same `id` on more than one element in the DOM. When you want to identify multiple elements, use a class or a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: Also, in your PHP you can use `'` to delimit the string so that you can use `"` within it without having to use the escape character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I clone the last row and increment the argument `$i` in the `onChange = \"CalcSale(this.form, $i);\"`

I wouldn't do that at all. I'd suggest using modern event handling, probably involving event delegation:

1. Don't output an `onChange` attribute on the `input` elements, but do include either classes or `data-*` attributes on them (perhaps `price-value` and `regular-price` classes).

2. Change the `CalcSale` function to accept a DOM event.

```
function CalcSale(event) { // <== Consider using standard JavaScript convention: `calcSale`
   const row = $j(event.target).closest("tr");
   const priceValue = row.find(".price-value");
   const regularPrice = row.find(".regular-price");
   // ...use `priceValue` and `regularPrice` jQuery objects
}
```

3. Hook up `CalcSale` like this:

```
$j("#page_prices").on("change", ".price-value, .regular-price", CalcSale);
```

(Consider adding the `input` event too: `.on("change input"`...)

Then your cloning code doesn't have to worry about incrementing a counter (and it's easier to *remove* rows as well), and your existing code works:

```
// (Not changed)
$j("#add_page_price").click(function(){
 $j("#page_prices tbody tr:last").clone().appendTo("#page_prices tbody");
})
```